# NiFi Database Connection for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-nifi

I am an old dog trying to learn new tricks.  My latest trick is building a data pipeline on home network in which a satellite data CSV on one Windows pc is picked up by a NiFi GetFile processor, passed to a NiFi PutDatabaseRecord processor, and a subset of fields from each of the CSV records is loaded into a Postgres database located on a Linux VM running on VirtualBox on a second pc.

My question is about PutDatabaseRecord, which requires a database connection.  From research it seems the most popular one to use is JDBC.  The Linux VM currently does not have Java installed; is it needed if I decide to use JDBC in NiFi?

Comment: NiFi is Java-based, so if you want to use NiFi, you need to install Java to run NiFi. In any case, don't ask multiple questions in one question on Stack Overflow. Also, the fact your database server is running on Linux and has no Java is irrelevant, the JDBC driver must be were NiFi is running.

Comment: Mark - thanks for your comments - post edited to single question.  Per your comments, and a piece I left out of question: On my second pc, where I have NiFi/Java installed on Windows, I should be good using a JDBC in NiFi PutDatabaseRecord without installing Java on VirtualBox/Linux VM. (The VM is hosting Postgres db, destination for CSV records from first pc.)

Comment: NiFi is what will be using the JDBC driver to connect to your PostgreSQL driver, so the driver must be where NiFi is running, not where your database is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnCalandra  No, your Linux VM (Postgresl host) does not need java.  NiFi will need java and already has java if you have it installed & running.

Comment: Thanks Steven - what you stated is precisely what I have going, so I am going to try the JDBC connector in NiFi/PutDatabaseRecord processor and see if I can connect to my Postgres db.